# How to do SQL queries (ORACLE) using Laravel?

Tags: sql, laravel, oracle

I wanted to know how to use `Laravel` framework in my projects, I'd like to use `Oracle` as my DB(cuz' is the db that I always use).

The First things that I find are "Entity Relational Model":

- One-to-One Relationships
- One-to-Many Relationships
- May to One Relationships
- Many-to-Many Relationships

But my doubt is, How be possible to do `SQL` queries with `Oracle` syntax on `Laravel`?

For Example, this Query (I Found on [internet](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/with-clause)):

```
WITH dept_count AS (
  SELECT deptno, COUNT(*) AS dept_count
  FROM   emp
  GROUP BY deptno)
SELECT e.ename AS employee_name,
       dc.dept_count AS emp_dept_count
FROM   emp e
       JOIN dept_count dc ON e.deptno = dc.deptno;
```

Sorry for my English, I speak Spanish :)

Comment: read about yajra/laravel-oci8

Comment: Just configure it to connect it to the database you want, and then use **eloquent.** Should be pretty simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute raw statements using the [`DB::raw`](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#raw-expressions) method of the database query builder. Think of it as pass-through statements.